# Input data on form is being created but not presisting values that are being passed, how do i solve this?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jstl

1. I have a OneToMany mapping set up for my student to address, so a student may have multiple addresses. The items are mapped correctly, but when I persist data through the form, the id is generated for the address(user is already created I just have to click add address, also I am getting the correct user) but the values are null when I save, here are my java and jsp snippets

```java
@PostMapping("/addAddress")
  public String showFormForAddAddress(@RequestParam("studentId") int id, Model model) {
      Student student = studentService.findStudentById(id);
      Address address = new Address();
      model.addAttribute("address", address);
      List<Address> addresses = student.getAddresses();
      addresses.add(address);
      student.setAddresses(addresses);
      studentService.saveStudent(student);

      return "address-form";
  }

  @GetMapping("/addAddress")
  public String addAddress(@RequestParam("studentId") int id, Model model) {
      Address address = new Address();
      address.setStudentId(id);
      model.addAttribute("address", address);
      return "address-form";
  }
```

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>



<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Address Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>SRM Student Relationship Manager (Address)</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <h3>Save Address</h3>
        <form:form action="addAddress" modelAttribute="address" method="POST">



              <form:input path="studentId" />

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Address One</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="addressOne" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>City</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="city" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>State</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="state" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Zip Code</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="zipCode" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Address Two</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="addressTwo" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Also for reassurance case these are my entities

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "address", catalog = "user_db")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String addressOne;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private String addressTwo;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer studentId;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student", catalog = "user_db")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id")
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

I feel like this may be a naming issue but I cant quite put my finger on it, also I tried deleting the post and just using get, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

this should be the `showForForAddMethod`

```java
@PostMapping("/addAddress")
    public String showFormForAddAddress(@RequestParam("studentId") int id, Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("address") Address address) {
        Student student = studentService.findStudentById(id);

        model.addAttribute("address", address);
        List<Address> addresses = student.getAddresses();
        addresses.add(address);
        student.setAddresses(addresses);
        studentService.saveStudent(student);

        return "redirect:/student/list";
    }
```

If I create a new object the information is not mapped and hence it is lost, but when I pass address as a model attribute in the parameters, this points to the student object

Answer (score 0):

In your `showFormForAddAddress` method, you wrote  `model.addAttribute("address", address);` this puts values into model attribute.

But you were trying to get address information from this method, it is wrong.

You can get the related information by using the below approach:

```
Map<String,Object> modelMap = model.getModel().asMap();
Object object = modelMap.get("address");
```

After that you can convert the resulted object into Address type and use it